# Set callback of native webcomponent from Angular

Tags: angular, native-web-component

I have a native webcomponent with a callback function 'myCallback'.

```js
<script>
    class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.myCallback = this.getAttribute("my-callback");
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            this.innerHTML = "MyComponent";

            const me = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                const cb = me.myCallback;
                if (typeof cb === "string") {
                    new Function(cb).call(window);
                } else if (typeof cb === "function") {
                    cb.call(window);
                } else {
                    console.log("not a function: " + cb);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

    }

    customElements.define("my-component", MyComponent);
</script>
```

I want to use this webcomponent in Angular and assign a callback to it but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have tried so far:

```js
<my-component my-callback="angularCallback()"></my-component>
<my-component my-callback="{{angularCallback}}"></my-component>
<my-component [my-callback]="angularCallback"></my-component>
<my-component [my-callback]="angularCallback()"></my-component>
<my-component (my-callback)="angularCallback()"></my-component>
```

The first line above throws the error "angularCallback is not a function" because it is not defined in the window, but in Angular. The other lines are never called and do not throw any error.

As a simple test I tried the following and it works fine:

```js
<my-component my-callback="console.log('test-callback');"></my-component>
```

Is there a way to assign the callback in Angular via the template?

**Update with solution**

The mistake that I made was that I tried `[my-callback]` instead of `[myCallback]`

So the solution is the following:

```
<my-component [myCallback]="angularCallback"></my-component>
```

Comment: Why can't you try emitting event from Custom Component to Angular Component.

Comment: Angular components don't work like web components. If you use Inputs/Outputs for your web component, you have to work around to get bindings or event listeners working. I suggest you a pretty recent youtube video that explains it well : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujaMvl5M8nY

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya are Events the standard way to trigger changes in web components? I chose callbacks because it seemed easier to implement. I want to use those webcomponents in different frameworks, not only in Angular. If it is best practice to use Events instead of callbacks then i will switch to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are passed down to a custom element as a string. When passing a function, it will be easier to pass it as a property on the custom element.

You could pass the property using the `[]` syntax in Angular.

```
<my-component [mycallback]="callbackMethod"></my-component>
```

The callbackMethod being a simple function in the ts code.

```
callbackMethod = () => console.log('callback method called');
```

Then in the custom web component, you can directly access the property value.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // directly access the callback property on the component
    const cb = this.mycallback;

    if (typeof cb === "string") {
        new Function(cb).call(window);
    } else if (typeof cb === "function") {
        cb.call(window);
    } else {
        console.log("not a function: " + cb);
    }
}, 1000);
```

I've created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9mu5u) to illustrate this.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I got it running now!